# Can the "Like Operator" be used with an array?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

Can I do something like this:

```
Sub RTtest2()

    Dim i As Variant
    Dim ArrTest As Variant

    ArrTest = Array("tag:(1???)?EX???", "tag:(3???)?EX???", "tag:(5???)?EX???")

    For Each i In ArrTest
        If "tag:(1001)FEXFFF" Like ArrTest(i) Then
            'Do something
        Else
            'Do something
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Specifically, can I use an array with the like operator?

Comment: This looks like a better fit for REGEX

Comment: I get a type mismatch error... but I don't know if that means I can't do this or if it means that I just have some small syntax error

Comment: `If "tag:(1001)FEXFFF" Like i Then` - you're using a `For Each` loop.

Comment: Does that mean you can not use an array with Like? Also... Why is REGEX a better fit? I am asking because I am not very familiar with REGEX (I just learned about it earlier today) and it looks as though the like operator is simpler to use.

Comment: BigBen!! Thank you!!

Comment: REGEX lets you search for explicitly defined patterns and thus will generate less false positives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using "Like" with an array... the array in this case is called "TagForms"

```
If wkbCompiledData_Table(1).Sheets(1).Cells(r, 2).Value Like TagForms(i) Then
    wkbCompiledData_Table.Add Workbooks.Open(FileName:=wkbCompiledData_Table(1).Sheets(1).Cells(r, 1).Value, WriteResPassword:="x")
End If
```